# WCF is applicable for my requirement?

Tags: .net, wcf

I am generating a chart for organization view. As of now i collect data from Database and generate XML file. This XML file will be input to the chart for display. The entire task takes more time to display the chart. 
I feel to create WCF service here to collect Database info and generate XML file.
Is it fruitful?
Thanks,
Rose

Answer (score 1):

Its a perfect choice. Building the service to expose your data. This would give you capablity to share the data between different application. Today its chart, tomorrow it could be some internal intranet web site. I would recommend you try and build either restful web services or
You could even use, [MVC Web API](http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-mvc-4-web-api/)

Restful Services scale pretty well and there are other numerous advantages compared to SOAP

Comment: Hi Anand, Will you prefer REST for this requirement? i am using VS 2008. 1) Need to connect database and collect data for particular EmpId 2) write into XML file(which is in the name of empID_ChartFile. Please help me in technically how to get implemented this and which technology to be used.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel to create WCF service here to collect Database info and
>   generate XML file. Is it fruitful?

If the created service has potential to be used from different kind of applications for ex. from silverlight you can go for WCF. When the component that makes the db interactions and generate xml has the capability to be reused in many places then making it as a service provides you easy maintenance and you can easily support many clients by adding new bindings and endpoints.

If there is only one client for the component I don't see much benefit in putting as a service. In fact service calls will be even more slower compared to directly calling the methods. There are chances you may have to spend hours to fix simple configuration issues all for a single client.

If there is only one client and the client calls the component methods in less no. of places then you can initially create a component and later at any point of time you can easily change it into a service by creating wrapper classes or even directly applying service attributes over the classes. Since there is only one client you can easily force the client to use the service instead of directly using the component.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your valuable inputs. Im developing this application for internal use which can be utilized by HRs and managers to view their team members and vacant positions. They can drill down till last node. So this will be a intranet application and used by many of the managers(more than 250) at the same time. More over my application supports one domain users only. There are few other applications which are for other domains (like Asian users, European users). So i prefer WCF service which gets different domains and create xml files)